# Get current path name in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I would like to be able to get the name of the current route in a request in Ruby on Rails. I've found ways I can access the controller and action of the request, but I would like to access a string or symbol of the name.

For example, if I have a `users` resource;

- If I go to /users/1 I would like to be able to get `users_path`
- If I go to /users/1/edit I would like to be able to get `edit_users_path`

I simply want to retrieve the name of the current route on a given request.

Comment: not sure i understand the question, but if you type rake routes in your terminal it will give you all of your paths

Comment: I know that `rake routes` will list the routes out for me, I want to get the name of the route during a single request.

Comment: Did you find out how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

The following code will give it to you.

```
Rails.application.routes.recognize_path(request.request_uri)
```

Note that there are a couple of exceptions that can get thrown in `ActionDispatch::Routing::RouteSet` (which is what is returned from `Rails.application.routes`) so be careful about those. You can find the implementation of the method [here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionDispatch/Routing/RouteSet/recognize_path).

Comment: In Rails 4 it seems I have to use `request.original_url` instead. When I do the response is `{:action=>"new", :controller=>"users"}`, when I am looking for `new_user_path`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following methods to get the current url in your action but none of them will give you the name of the route like `users_path`

```
request.original_url # => www.mysite.com/users/1

request.request_uri # = > /users/1
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to use `request.original_fullpath` (Rails 5.2)

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `current_page?` method to achieve this.

```
current_page?(user_path(@user))
current_page?(edit_user_path(@user))
```

Here's a link:
[current_page? method](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/current_page%3F)